# Ansible prompts password when using synchronize

Tags: ssh, passwords, rsync, synchronize, ansible

I'm using [ansible](http://www.ansible.com) in the following way:

`ansible-playbook -f 1 my-play-book.yaml --ask-pass --ask-sudo-pass`

After this I'm asked to enter the ssh & sudo passwords (same password for both).

Inside my playbook file I'm using synchronize task:

`synchronize: mode=push src=rel/path/myfolder/ dest=/abs/path/myfolder/`

For each host, I'm prompted to enter the ssh password of the remote host (the same that I entered in the beginning of the playbook run)

How can I avoid entering the password when executing synchronize task?

Comment: Can you setup ssh keys to use instead or are passwords a requirement?

Comment: I tried to setup the keys and i'm able to ssh manually without entering a password. But when I try it via ansible i'm asked to enter a password.

Comment: Even if you remove `--ask-pass` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

If you have setup the ssh keys correctly on the <host>, then the following should work.

```
ansible all -m synchronize -a "mode=push src=rel/path/myfolder/ dest=/abs/path/myfolder/" -i <host>, -vvv
```

I was able to get the above working without any password prompt.