# Ansible synchronize asking for a password

Tags: deployment, rsync, ansible

I am using Ansible (1.9.2) to deploy some files to a Redhat 6.4 server.

The playbook looks something like this

```
- name: deploy files
  hosts: web
  tasks:
    - name sync files
      sudo: no
      synchronize:
        src={{ local_path }}
        dest={{ dest_path }}
```

And to kick this off I run something like the following

```
ansible-playbook -i myinventory myplaybook.yml -u DOMAIN\\user --ask-pass
```

When I start the play I enter my password at the prompt, facts are then obtained successfully, however as soon as the *synchronize* task is reached another prompt asks for my password again, like the following

```
DOMAIN\user@hostname's password:
```

If I enter my password again the deploy completes correctly.

**My questions are**

1. How can I fix or work around this, so that I do not have to enter my password for every use of the synchronize module?
2. Is this currently expected behaviour for the synchronize module? Or is this a bug in Ansible?

I cannot use ssh keys due to environment restrictions.

I do not want to use the copy module for scalability reasons.

**Things I have tried**

1. I have seen a number of other questions on this subject but I have
   not been able to use any of them to fix my issue or understand if
   this is expected behavior.

   - [Ansible synchronize prompts passphrase even if already entered at the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763343/ansible-synchronize-prompts-passphrase-even-if-already-entered-at-the-beginning)
   - [Ansible prompts password when using synchronize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504430/ansible-prompts-password-when-using-synchronize)
   - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5934
   - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/7071
2. The Ansible docs are generally excellent but I have not been able to find anything about this on the offical docs.
3. I have tried specifiying the user and password in the inventory file and not using the *--ask-pass* and *-u* parameters. But while I then do not have to enter the password to collect facts, the synchronize module still requests my password.
4. I have tried setting the *--ask-sudo-pass* as well, but it did not help
5. I have been using a CentOS 7 control box, but I have also tried an Ubuntu 14.04 box

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have similar issue. As I see ansible is trying to rsync from root user when ansible_sudo == true.

Comment: Ansible docs are quite bad actually. Documentation looks more like a bunch of low quality tutorials at this time.

Answer (score 1):

To pass a password to synchronize module you can use --password-file option like so.

```
tasks:
- name: test_rsync
  synchronize:
    mode: pull
    src: rsync://user@host/your/remote/path
    dest: /your/local/path/
    rsync_opts:
      - "--password-file=/path/to/password_file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use inventory like below encrypted with [Vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html) (ansible-playbook –ask-vault-pass …)?:

```
[targets]
other1.example.com    ansible_connection=ssh    ansible_ssh_user=mpdehaan   ansible_ssh_pass=foobar
other2.example.com    ansible_connection=ssh    ansible_ssh_user=mdehaan    ansible_ssh_pass=foobar123
```

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize will ask you for password if your ansible server credential is different from you target host. I've tried many proposed workarounds however none of them worked...

Eventually I had to go back to file module using --sftp-extra-args to achieve what I needed. It did the trick.

Comment: We still do not have a fix for this from Ansible ? :(

Comment: Ansible's synchronize module  is very limited to a small number of scenarios, i recommend using something like this:

      - name: downloading file
        command: "curl -o /opt/files/my_file_name"
        args:
          warn: false
        async: 7200
        poll: 120

Answer (score 0):

I used the Shell for that.

```
- name: test_rsync
  shell: rsync -a --delete --rsh='/usr/bin/sshpass -p "{{ pass }}" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l $RemoteUser' {{ local_path }} $RemoteUser@{{ inventory_hostname }}:/{{ dest_path }}
  become: false
  delegate_to: localhost     #If needed
```

The password is encrypted with Ansible-Vault and saved under /vars/main.yml